# How can to see off screen content at design time in Blend or VS for Windows Phone 7 or 8

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, xaml, expression-blend, windows-phone-8

I am designing a long Windows Phone 8 page. It is very frustrating that I can't see most of it in the design visuals.

I was wondering if anyone knows a way of being able to see the content visually, at design time, of either the bottom of the page (i.e. scrolling up in the designer), or preferable to be able to see the whole page.

I know you can turn the chrome off, is there any way to turn the view windows masking frame off?

This also applies to trying to see a whole panorama view too!
Thanks

Comment: Since I'm not sure if this is exactly what you mean so placed as comment instead of an answer for now. However try removing your d:DesignWidth / d:DesignHeight declarations to allow the entire view to be displayed in your artboard.

Comment: @NER1808 Instead of removing  d:DesignWidth / d:DesignHeight, just set these values high enough such that all of your content gets displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Try temporarily collapsing the controls which are above the controls which is getting off screen. Later you can set that control to required dimensions again.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of removing `d:DesignWidth` & `d:DesignHeight` from xaml root tag, just set these values high enough such that all of your content gets displayed.